# Print POST JSON data

Tags: json, go, post, handler

I have an issue printing the JSON from the POST.
I use `gorilla/mux` for routing

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/test", Point).Methods("POST")
http.ListenAndServe(":80", r)`
```

and in `Point` function I have

```
func Point(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var callback Decoder
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&callback)
}
```

But I can use this method only when I know the structure and I want to figure out how to `log.Print` the whole JSON as a string. I tried

```
func Point(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    log.Println(r.Form)
}
```

But it prints an empty map. Please help to figure out this.

Comment: [ParseForm](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) is for parsing `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content, not `application/json`.

Comment: If you check my answer and just go to the point after the ioutil.ReadAll() part.  's' is a byte[] which you can log / print out / do what you want with.  It'd also mean you wouldn't need to do the 'struct' part.

Comment: Id also reccommend updating your question title to be something like:

'How do I parse and print out a JSON POST http request'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the assumption that you are building a standard API endpoint which receives some JSON and you would like to do something with it you should approach it the following way.

**Edit:**

> As mentioned in the comments when you use the ioutil.ReadAll()
>   function as in this example it will read everything that is sent in the
>   post request into the application memory.  It's a good idea to check
>   this in a production application (e.g limiting payload size).

1.) Make a struct which will hold the data coming from an API post request in GoLang
2.) Convert your request body into a byte array `[]byte`
3.) `Unmarshal` your `[]byte` into a single instance of your struct made earlier.

I'll put an example below:

## 1. Make a struct which you'll put your JSON into.

---

Let's take an example of a simple blog post.

The JSON object looks like this and has a `slug`, a `title`, and `description`

```javascript
{
  "slug": "test-slug",
  "title": "This is the title",
  "body": "This is the body of the page"
}
```

So your struct would look like this:

```go
type Page struct {
    Slug  string `json:"slug"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Body  string `json:"body"`
}
```

## 2 - 3. Get the body of your request and convert it to `byte[]` Then take that string and `Unmarshal` it into an instance of your struct.

---

The data of a post request is the request 'Body'.

In Golang the request in almost all cases (unless you're using something fancy outside of the defaults) will be an http.Request object.  This is the 'r' which you normally have in your normal code and it holds the 'Body' of our POST request.

```go
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi" // you can remove
    "github.com/go-chi/render" // you can remove but be sure to remove where it is used as well below.
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)


func GiveMeAPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("A page"))
}
```

So what we are going to do here is convert an `io.ReadCloser`, which is what the `http.Request.Body` is, to a `[]byte` as the `Unmarshal` function takes a `[]byte` type.  I've commented inline below for you.

```
func Create(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var p Page //Create an instance of our struct


    //Read all the data in r.Body from a byte[], convert it to a string, and assign store it in 's'.
    s, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body) 
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // This would normally be a normal Error http response but I've put this here so it's easy for you to test.
    }
    // use the built in Unmarshal function to put the string we got above into the empty page we created at the top.  Notice the &p.  The & is important, if you don't understand it go and do the 'Tour of Go' again.
    err = json.Unmarshal(s, &p)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // This would normally be a normal Error http response but I've put this here so it's easy for you to test.
    }

   // From here you have a proper Page object which is filled.  Do what you want with it.

    render.JSON(w, r, p) // This is me using a useful helper function from go-chi which 'Marshals' a struct to a json string and returns it to using the http.ResponseWriter.
}
```

> **As a side note.  Please don't use `Decoder` to parse JSON unless you are using JSON streams.  You are not here, and it's unlikely you will
>   for a while. You can read about why that is
>   [here](https://ahmet.im/blog/golang-json-decoder-pitfalls/)**

Comment: Blindly calling ioutil.ReadAll on the request body is a pretty bad idea. Clients can trivially run the server out of memory that way. You should check the ContentLength field first, and use an io.LimitReader if it's -1. Also, it is not necessary to drain the request body (the server will always close it anyway). Using json.Decoder is just fine for requests.

Comment: Yeah you're totally correct on that one @Peter!  I didn't want to over complicate the answer though so the answer to the question was still obvious.

I'll add a one liner saying that people should still be checking if the JSON they are reading is safe to do so / they put some restrictions on what gets sent to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the raw JSON data without parsing it, `http.Request.Body` implements `io.Reader`, so you can just `Read` from it. For example with `ioutil.ReadAll`.

Something like (untested):

```
func Point(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    // check error
    // do whatever you want with the raw data (you can `json.Unmarshal` it too)
}
```